# Composer install error

Tags: php, installation, composer-php, phar

I have been testing laravel in my local development environment. When I try to upload my sample project to my testing server, I realize I need to upgrade from php 5.2.17 to 5.3.15 (and install composer). I started having problems.

I use http to install because composer was complaining about ssl (even when I have `extension=php_openssl.dll` enabled

I have the following behavior:

```
$ curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off -d allow_url_fopen=On
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

The openssl extension is missing, which will reduce the security and stability of Composer.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /xxx/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

$ php composer.phar
??????????$
```

So, every command I try to use over composer (help about info) return the `???` message.
What's happening?

Thanks for answering, I can't see anyone with this same error

Comment: I wonder why you see a need to pass all these additional configuration settings to PHP during install. They shouldn't be necessary. On the other hand: You really need a good working PHP installed, but you don't need PHP 5.3 on the server if you upload the installed libraries from your local machine and execute Composer there (most libraries require PHP 5.3 by themself, but that's not connected with Composer).

Comment: Thanks for answering. The configuration settings were there because I didn't want to fall in security issues changing config in php.ini. The php upgrade was due I didn't wan't to have bogus errors due laravel's code based on php5.3... Anyway, I had myself forced to change php.ini and that fixed my problems. Then I realized that I had to paste the config in every composer call via CLI... A truly pain

Answer (score 1):

Finally I changed the php.ini code (CLI version) to cover composer's needs, that helped me with the extra text in every CLI command. Then apache restart and finally got it working. Thanks all for your help

Comment: What changes did you make?

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan I just added `detect_unicode=Off` and `allow_url_fopen=On` in my php.ini file. The command `php -d XXX` originally overwrite those command if not enabled